# Stuck with character encoding in php

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have imported data from excel sheet to mysql and phpmyadmin is showing data in correct encoding or you can say in a readable form like

```
51cm (20¼”)
41cm (16¼”)
```

However when i try to display this data in my application it is displaying it as

```
51cm (6Â½â)
```

i think there is problem with " this symbol....

How can I fix this.. I have already tried using

```
htmlspecialchars_decode()

html_entity_decode()
```

but no solution so far.. Any help will be deeply appreciated.
Thanks ...

Comment: Have you set the mysql connection mode to UTF-8 and also set PHP headers (or html content-type) to UTF-8?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> its already in the header and also mysql connection mode is already UTF-8

Comment: `header('Content-Type', "text/html; charset=utf-8")` in front is more important than `<meta>`. Check in your browser the encoding, the page is probable not in UTF-8, as `Â½â` is very typical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your script is converting text that is already in UTF-8 from ISO-8859-1 (or less likely, Windows-1252) to UTF-8.

Look for something like a [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/utf8_encode) call that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

For special charters encoding you have to do below possible solutions :

1) Add meta tag in header `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

2) Use `html_entity_decode($data_value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
html_entity_decode($data_value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: already tried, but not working..

Answer (score 0):

please try this if it works `

```
htmlentities($data_value);`
```